# How to schedule each step of jobset separately by schedule job element in soa suite bpel 12c using Enterprise scheduler service(ESS)?

Tags: oracle, jobs, schedule, soa-suite, oracle-enterprise-manager

I want to schedule a jobset step separately in oracle SOA suite 12c in jdeveloper.

For example I want to schedule the first step to be run today at 15:00 pm and second step to be run tomorrow.

Is it possible? If yes, then how it would be possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "jobset step"?

Comment: in enterprise manager in the enterprise scheduling services part, in the ESS app , in the job metadata part we can define JOBSets, each job set has it's own steps @Joe